# sqlBulkCopy Aspx Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual, aspx

Buen día gente.

Ando trabajando en un proceso que me vacíe los datos de un gridview en una tabla en sql, pero no me termina de hacer lo que quiero, visto desde el proceso de interrupción si me agarra todos los datos del gridview ( Es solamente una columna). Ese gridview lo lleno previamente de un archivo Excel. Pero al momento de vaciarlo a una tabla no ocurre, se hecho me continua el proceso de manera normal, no me guarda la información pero tampoco me lanza algun error (llega al mensaje del label)

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("Num_Inventario", GetType(String))
        For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim Num_Inventario As String = gvrow.Cells(0).Text
            dt.Rows.Add(Num_Inventario)
        Next
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
            con.Open()
            Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "bienes_temporal"
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt)
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Label3.Text = "Se Actualizó Correctamente"
```

¿Me pueden instruir en que esta mal o que me puede faltar? Gracias

Comment: Creo que deberías validar primeramente si se realiza la conexión.

Comment: Supongo que si se efectua ya que es la misma conexión para otros procesos dentro del mismo proyecto. 
(Si me modifica las tablas cuando guardo de manera normal con un commandText de SQL)